# how can i write this sql in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This SQL is working fine in mysql for testing purpose, i am getting the street_address_extracted from it

```
select *, regexp_substr(trim(street_address), '^\\d+\\s+\\w+') street_address_extracted from user_listings WHERE is_found_before = 0
```

But when i run this query in laravel as i don't get the street_address_extracted field results its always blank but when manually raun into phpmyadmin i get 1000s of rows.

Here is how i wrote this into laravel

```
DB::select(DB::raw("select *, regexp_substr(trim(street_address), '^\\d+\\s+\\w+') street_address_extracted from user_listings WHERE is_found_before = 0"));
```

[image: street_address_extracted is blank]

when ran manually in phpmyadmin i get this.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
DB::table('user_listings')
    ->selectRaw("*, regexp_substr(trim(street_address), '^\\d+\\s+\\w+') AS street_address_extracted")
    ->where('is_found_before', 0)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Tried your query and obviously used get() but still street_address_extracted is blank for some reason it seems like its not even running

Comment: You may also need the `AS` keyword. I've seen the QueryBuilder be a little finicky about it. `regexp_substr(trim(street_address), '^\\d+\\s+\\w+') AS street_address_extracted`

Comment: still same, i have uploaded an image of what i get.

Comment: @LearningPHPOOP try replacing `->get()` with `->toSql()` and see the query, maybe will help to debug.

Comment: @Froxz this is what i see after replacing to toSqlL() "select *, regexp_substr(trim(street_address), '^\d+\s+\w+') AS street_address_extracted from `user_listings` where `is_found_before` = ?" and whatever SQL it gave me i tried running this manually to phpmyadmin and it didn't return back street_address_extract so it seems like its not preparing up a correct SQL statement

Comment: @Froxz it seems like its escaping double backslashes \\ in regex and preparing only one \ .. fixed

Comment: @Froxz seems right to me. I had faced a similar issue once when when I had to manually (without using relationships) write a `where` query like `WHERE field = 'App\\\Models\\\Example'`. I had to put `\\\\` which in turn used get converted to `\\\`